# Routing issue after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, form-for

So I'm still a Rails noob so I may be completely going at this wrong but I have two controllers. A Question Controller and an Answer Controller. I am trying to build a grading function that allows an admin user to assign points to essay questions. I am using the `/answer/:id` to be where the :id is the id of the question and then rendering a partial to iterate through all of the answers for that id. Clear as mud I'm sure...

My problem: Within the partial where the user's answer is displayed, I have a form that allows the admin to fill out the number of points for that answer and submit. Ideally, I'd like it to move to the next page (using will_paginate), but at a minimum, I'd like to stay on the same page. I am able to get the form working but it keeps going to /answers/:id but where :id is the id of the individual answer, so not what I'm hoping.

answers_controller.rb

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @user = current_user
    @questions = Question.all

  end


  def show
    @user = current_user
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @answers = Answer.where("question_id = ?", @question.id).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 1)
    @answer = Answer.where("question_id =? AND user_id = ?", @question.id, @user.id)
  end

  def edit
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    if @answer.update_attributes(grade_params)
      flash[:success] = "Answer Graded"
    else
      flash[:warning] = "Not Graded"
    end
  end

  private

  def grade_params
    params.require(:answer).permit(:points_earned)
  end

end
```

_essay_grades.html.erb (partial that is being rendered on the show page that contains the form)

```
<% @answers.each do |answer| %>
<p>User: <%= answer.user_id %></p>
<%= answer.answer %><br>
<%= @question.value %>
<br>
  <%= form_for(answer) do |f| %>

  <%#= f.radio_button :points_earned, @question.value %><br>
  <%#= f.radio_button :points_earned, 0 %> <br>
  <%= f.text_field :points_earned %> Points<br>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit "Award Points" %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
<br>
<br>

<%= will_paginate @answers, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  resources :admins, :answers, :static_pages, :questions

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }, 
     :path => '', :path_names => 
    { :sign_in => "login", :sign_up => "register" }


  root "static_pages#index"
end
```

I'm sure there's a simple solution here (or maybe it's changing how I have things set up...). Any help is greatly appreciated!

**AFTER FEEDBACK:** 
Added the grades model and set up a through relationship with questions.

answer_controller.rb

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController


  def show
    @user = current_user
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @answers = Answer.where("question_id = ?", @question.id).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 1)
    @answer = Answer.where("question_id =? AND user_id = ?", @question.id, @user.id)
  end



  def update
    @user = current_user
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = @question.answers.find(params[:id])

    @grade = @question.grades.new(grade_params)

    if @grade.save
      flash[:success] = "Answer Graded"
      redirect_to @question
    end
  end

      private

      def grade_params
        params.require(:grade).permit(:user_id, :answer_id, :points_earned, :graded_by, :comment)
      end

    end
```

_answer.html.erb

```
<%= answer.user_id %>
<%= form_tag [@question, answer], method: :put do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :graded_by, current_user.id %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :answer_id, answer.id %>


    <%= number_field_tag :points_earned %>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit Grade" %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :questions do
    resources :answers, only: [:update]
  end

  resources :admins, :static_pages
```

questions/show.html.erb

```
...
<h3>Show answers</h3>
<%= render @answers, locals: {question: @question} %>
<%= will_paginate @answers, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on the question, but `<%= form_for answer, remote: true do |f| %>` might be what you're looking for, it'll prevent a link to a new url.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the following in your form so the update does not load a new page, but still submits your update. Use Chrome / Firefox developer tools to view requests / responses.

```
<%= form_for(answer), :remote => true do |f| %>
```

Then, alter the update action in the answers controller to load the 'next unrated answer':

```
def update
  rated_answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
  if rated_answer.update_attributes(grade_params)
    flash[:success] = "Answer Graded"
  else
    flash[:warning] = "Not Graded"
  end
  @answer = get_next_unrated_answer(rated_answer.question_id)
end

private

def get_next_unrated_answer(question_id)
  # I am making a couple of assumptions on your model here, but get an answer that has not been rated yet for this question
  next_answer = Answer.where("question_id = ? and points_earned = ?", question.id, nil)
  #returned automatically
end
```

Then you will have to create app/views/answers/update.js.erb to load the new answer to your page with the following line:

```
$('#main_div').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'whatever_partial_you_have_created_to_display_the_next_unrated_answer') %>');
```

Just go and create a new partial that displays your answer and form correctly for the next unrated answer. Or ideally load your initial 'show.html.erb' with the relevant partials and reuse them.

This is the simple way to do it, but if I were you I would probably rename these new functions to not use 'update' or 'show' but rather call it something like 'rate' and even 'rate_show' so you can use update and show in its original form (for updating and answer or showing an answer) if required later in your project.

Comment: Perfect! I will look to try this out once I clean some of the other stuff up as well. I like the idea of being able to iterate through the pages as one submits a grade so hopefully this will work! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood of your question, I think you'd be best looking into [`nested routes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :questions do
   resources :answers, only: [:update]
end

#app/controllers/questions_controller.rb
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @question = Question.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/questions/show.html.erb
<%= @question.title %>
<%= render @question.answers, locals: {question: @question} %>

#app/views/questions/_answer.html.erb
<%= answer.title %>
<%= form_tag [question, answer], method: :put do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :grade %>
    <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

The above will give you what you have already (just to clarify your "clearly mad" remark is not the case *at all*!).

-

The following is where the nested resources come in.

At the moment, it seems you're having a problem associating an answer to a question:

> where `:id` is the id of the individual answer, so not what I'm hoping

A remedy for this is as follows:

```
#app/controllers/answers_controller.rb
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
   def update
      @question = Question.find params[:question_id]
      @answer = @question.answers.find params[:id]

      @grade = @answer.grades.new grade_params
      redirect_to @question if @grade.save
   end

   private

   def grade_params
      params.permit(:points_earned) #-> will probably have to refactor this
   end
end
```

This will create a new `grade` (which you should have in an associated model), for that specific answer. Because the answer has been associated to a `question`, it will allow you to use the nested routes to load both.

In terms of your setup, I'd personally add a `Grade` model, so that you can have multiple grades per answer. This is against your current schema, but works well to ensure you have the functionality necessary to facilitate multiple grades:

```
#app/models/grade.rb
class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :answer
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/answer.rb
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :grades
end
```

Comment: I made some of your suggested changes. I keep running into an "undefined method `permit' for "1":String" error on the params.require statement. I can't figure out. The params hash, seems to have all of the info required to create the grade object. I also tried changing the grade input to a number as I set it up as an integer.

Comment: Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"8UhJhKm9V6Mejxfm2uMpTPTP+4eGhxzfwpgJyc9k9afOG61iy/BjLPwJJUeiFFNMXqBOS3+2axlno/fbWagq+A==",
 "graded_by"=>"1",
 "answer_id"=>"20",
 "grade"=>"1",
 "commit"=>"Submit Grade",
 "question_id"=>"1",
 "id"=>"20"}